# Customize notice message for each parameter on update?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**Goal:** to have a unique message per either each parameter or set of paramters.

**I have this code in my controller update:**

```
def update
    @order = Order.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @order.update_attributes(order_status)
        # if @order.changed == [:order_status]
          format.html { redirect_to @order, notice: 'Order was successfully cancelled.' }
          format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @order }
      #   else
      #     format.html { render :edit }
      #     format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      #   # end
      # end
    elsif @order.update(order_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @order, notice: 'Order was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @order }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

private

def order_params
      params.require(:order).permit(:name, :name_2, :email, :phone_number)
    end

    def order_status
      params.require(:order).permit(:order_status)
    end
```

Though, no matter which parameter i update, I always get the message "'Order was successfully cancelled.", even when I don't update `:order_status` at all.

I have tried many many combinations but I cannot get a unique message to work.  Everything still updates, just not with the messages i want.  I have tried not using `elsif`, not defining `@order`, different orders, user `.update` and `.update_attributes`, using `@order.update(params[:order_status])`, etc.

What can I do here to have custom messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if @order.update(order_status)
  if @order.order_status_previously_changed?
    format.html { redirect_to @order, notice: 'Order was successfully cancelled.' }
    ...
```

Rails uses [ActiveRecord::Dirty](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html) to keep track of changes to the model during and after updates.  You can also use it to see what attributes were changed (`@order.order_status_changed?`), what they were originally, and what they changed too (`@order.order_status_changed?(from: :open, to: :cancelled)`). This would give you finer control over the response. Note that the last two examples would need to be implemented before the order object is saved.

Comment: I think the changes are only available in the model's callback cycle. Like `after_update`, `after_save`, etc. But OP could make such a callback and use a virtual attribute to pass them to the controller.

Comment: If you look at the documentation I linked it is available outside callbacks.

Comment: oh, my bad then. I just tested with my work application and they must not have configured the models with `ActiveRecord::Dirty` in a way which supports that.

Comment: Quick test works, thank you.  `if @order.update_attributes(order_status) && @order.order_status_previously_changed?` worked and both messages worked.  will slim the code down.  thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Say you don't provide a value for `params[:order_status]`. Then the method `order_status` will return an empty hash. Well, technically it's an instance of [`ActionController::Parameters`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html), but is behaves like a hash:

```
ActionController::Parameters.superclass
# => ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess

ActionController::Parameters.superclass.superclass
# => Hash

params = ActionController::Parameters.new(order: {foo: "bar"})
params.require(:order).permit(:order_status)
# => {}
```

Running [`update`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update/class) or [`update_attributes`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update_attributes) with an empty hash *will be succesful*. That's why your first `if` condition is being met. As a fix, you can do something quite simple:

```
if order_stats.present? && @order.update_attributes(order_status)
```

The [`Object#present?`](https://apidock.com/rails/Object/present%3F) method will check that object is truthy and non-empty. It's the opposite of [`Object#blank?`](https://apidock.com/rails/Object/blank%3F)